# CSS Transition Font awesome content

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I wan't to be able to animate a font awesome pseudo element.

Heres my HTML

```
<li class="has-submenu">
    <a onclick="$(this).toggleClass('open').closest('.has-submenu').find('.submenu').toggleClass('closed')" class="parent" href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-text-o"></i> <span class="sidebar-collapse-hide">Reports</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
            <a href="/cases">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i> <span class="sidebar-collapse-hide">Cases</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/time">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="sidebar-collapse-hide">Facility Time</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Lets say I have a pseudo element like this

```
.parent:after {
   content: '\f0da';
   font-family:"FontAwesome";
   position: absolute;
   right: 15px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

How can I make it so that when I add a class to the parent element, it changes the content and animates it.

```
.parent {
   &.open:after {
     content: '\f0d7'!important;
   }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is have a right arrow on a menu item, then when its clicked, add the 'open' class and change the content to a down arrow. But i'd like it to animate the rotation from right to down. Is it possible?

Comment: Please add your HTML Code

Comment: No, it is not possible to “animate” between different font characters. You should keep the same icon, but actually rotate the element instead - that is something you _can_ animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using transform: rotate() and a transition effect.

```js
$('.parent').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.parent {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.parent:after {
  content: "\f0da";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.parent.open:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="parent">Parent element</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll do it this way :) was just curious as to whether or not you could animate the content itself.